# Use array of objects as model on child angular component and watch for changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that displays a list of items (objects). I want to create another component that receives this list as its model (or as a parameter) and creates a dashboard with this data. For example, I have a list of products, with quantity and price per unit, and want to display on the child component the total price.

By creating the component and passing the list to the child the total price is displayed correctly, however, when new items are added to the list, or when the quantity/price of an item is changed inside the list, my child component does not get triggered and does not updates it self.

I already tried to use `ControlValueAccessor` and `OnChanges`

Code on parent

`<result [(ngModel)]="productList" [test]="armorList"></result>`

Code on child - I know that using model and input might not be correct, I just tried both , sot sure which would be better.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
import { Armor, Material } from "../armor-list.component";
import * as _ from "lodash";


@Component({
    selector: 'result',
    templateUrl: './result.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./result.component.css'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ResultComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class ResultComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

    @Input() test: Product[];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log(changes);
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        if (obj !== undefined && obj !== null) {
           //logic to calculate the price
        }
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code to the question?

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: ControlValueAccessor is used to create custom form controls. It shouldn't be used here. All you need is the input. Add a method totalPrice() computing and returning the total price, and use it from the template: `Total price = {{ totalPrice() }}`. If you want to compute the total price only when something changes, you'll have to replace the array by another array in the parent so that the ngOnChanges is called in the child, and compute it there.

Comment: I want it to update everytime there is a change on the parent list. It does not make sense to recreate the array if I just changed a property on it. Is there another way to do it? Or should I give up of having this in a separated component?

Answer (score 1):

Angular detects changes in array and object by reference (not by value). Since you have just added an item to array, its reference stills remain same.

So to detect changes in array, you need to adopt either of the following strategies.

1. Use ngDoCheck lifecycle hook. See https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks.
2. Use slice method on input array. Whenever you are adding items to array, modify input array as let input = originalArray.slice(0). This will give you a new reference address which angular can detect.